# What is the register of "to be shamed"?

Tags: register

I was wondering in what conditions is it considered as correct to use "to be shamed" ? **What is the register of this verb ?**

Comment: It's neither informal nor pompous. Could you provide some full example sentences illustrating your concern?

Comment: For example, writing in an essay : "She was shamed by this situation"

Comment: To be shamed, this is just consist of to verb add passive.

Comment: Linguistically, _register_ is a collection of vocabulary and syntax, amongst other things that are strongly linked to social stratification. While it is sometimes possible to comment on register based purely on a verb or verb phrase (_ain't_, for instance), what you're presented is insufficient to pass judgement on. The attempt below is merely a definition of the _active_ verb phrase (which can definitely index the register). Please add context, including full clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'To be shamed' is for someone to shame you, e.g. if you were to pee on my floor I would 'shame' you (call you out on it and try to make you embarrassed or apologetic).

"Sean shamed Trevor for peeing on his floor"

If you were to describe yourself feeling shame, you would be 'ashamed'

'Trevor was ashamed that he had peed on Sean's floor'

It has neither an informal nor formal register, although definitely not colloquial, certainly not formal in it's particulars

Answer (score 1):

The register of this verb is fairly neutral. You would be fine using it in formal writing, but you will also hear it in everyday speech.